# I can't store UTF8 string into mysql correctly wihch does not begin with a Ascii string

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

When I store a file(utf8) into mysql(utf8),the field like '汉字' can't be stored correctly.
But when I change the ‘汉字' to 'a汉字',which begin with a ascii char,it can be stored correctly. 
I use php(codeigniter) to read the file and all is configured with utf8.

Comment: try to change your column type also `utf-8-bin`.

Comment: [UTF-8 All the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Do you know the reason? I can't change mysql configure because the problem  only occurs in product environment(I can't access it),but the code runs correctly in test environment even I does not change ’汉字' to ‘a汉字'.

Comment: What symptoms do you have?  Question marks?  Truncated text?  Mojibake?  Other?

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` so we can see what got stored in the table.